# Need some help with Terminal Emulator (Android app) commands. (Similar to Linux commands)

Tags: linux, terminal, shell, android, root

I'm trying to follow [this](http://support.mobiledefense.com/viewtopic.php?id=569) tutorial to install Mobile Defense as a system application on my Motorola Droid.  I want to use [Terminal Emulator](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-android-term-jpAz.aspx) and the commands are basically the same.  The only two commands I don't know how to do on the Terminal Emulator is "adb shell" (to open up a remote shell - is this necessary?) and "adb push" in the [Android Debug Bridge](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html).  How can I do this in the Terminal Emulator?  If you're not familiar with Terminal Emulator, it is my understanding that it uses basic Linux Command Line commands.

I tried rsh for abd shell, and that didn't work.  And another user on here told me cp would replace adb push, but Terminal Emulator didn't recognize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Droid does not come with a cp (copy) command, but cat should provide similar functionality.

```
cat filename1 > filename2
```

So, if your APK resides in /sdcard/apk, Step 9 would look like:`cat /sdcard/apk/com.neevo.mobiledefense.apk > /system/app/com.neevo.mobiledefense.apk`

Everything else in the tutorial works the same in Terminal Emulator as Android Debug Bridge.

Answer (score 1):

The adb commands are meant to be run from the host machine that your phone is connected to via USB. The adb utility is installed with the Android SDK on your development machine.

The "adb shell" command, when run from your host machine, will open a shell that connects you to your Android device. It seems like you are trying to run the shell directly on your Droid. That may work fine for the commands in Steps 4-6 of the Mobile Defense tutorial, but I'm not sure.

There may also be a way to do the adb push directly on your phone. I'm not sure about that either but maybe someobody else will have an authoritative answer. In the end, it is probably just easier to install the Android SDK to gain access to the adb tool. The author of the tutorial assumes that you do have access to the adb tool somehow.

Comment: Thank you for the information about the Shell. :)

The "cat" command in the Terminal Emulator works similarly to "abd push."

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if your using the terminal emulator app you just put

```
cp /filedirectory/filename filedirectory
```

Note there is a space located between `cp` and the `file`, and in between the file and the directory your pasting it to. The second space acts as the word "to" . I hope I didn't make it sound complicated.